# How can I create MacOS' Help button in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter

The [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/buttons/help-buttons/) describe a distinctive Help button that isn't the same design as a normal tkinter button. My question is simply, can I create this button in tkinter? I looked in the tkinter docs on effbot, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: you maybe able to do this with `tkmacosx` also, you need show your effort in creating the button, we're not here to do your work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a button, put a question mark image on it, and set borders to 0.

Here is an example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.config(bg="light grey")
helpim = PhotoImage(file="help.gif")

help = Button(root, bd=0, bg="light grey")
help["activebackground"] = "light grey"
help.config(image=helpim)
help.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This is the question mark image I used:

[image]

You can assign the button a command to show the help as a [dialog message box](https://pythonspot.com/tk-message-box/).
Output:

[image]